# SelectedIndexChanged event not firing with OnChange method in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Please help me with a problem I'm having with a `DropDownList`. I'm using the JavaScript "onchange" method to get the DropDownList's selected value. I can get the value, but the `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event not firing. Hopefully someone can help me. My JavaScript function for getting selected value is:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function showAddress_Byamit()
    { 
         var e = document.getElementById("TabC_tp1_ddlcountry");
         var country = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
    }
 </Script>

<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlcountry" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
     Height="20px" EnableViewState="true"  TabIndex="4"  
     OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlcountry_SelectedIndexChanged" 
     onchange="showAddress_Byamit();return false" Width="100px" >
</asp:DropDownList>
```

The problem is that the `"ddlcountry_SelectedIndexChanged"` method is not called.

In the codebehind I have added the `Onchange` event as follows:

```
  ddlcountry.Attributes.Add("onchange", "showAddress_Byamit(); return false");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove `return false`

```
 ddlcountry.Attributes.Add("onchange", "showAddress_Byamit();");
```